# Save Input Value to Local Storage and Retrieve it on a different Page

Tags: javascript, local-storage, textinput

I have a webpage with 3 different pages: page1, page2 and page3.
On the first page, the user will type his name in a textbox.
I want to store that value to local storage to use again on page2 and page3.

I cannot even retrieve it on page1. Am I doing something wrong?
And I have no idea how to retrieve it on a different page. Any help?

```js
function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello, " + name + "! Welcome!";
}

localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userName");
```

```html
<p>What is your name?</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Name Surname">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>

<p id="greeting"></p>
<p id="storedName"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to make a few changes:

```js
function getName() {
  return localStorage.getItem("userName");
}

function updateHTML() {
  var name = getName();
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello, " + name + "! Welcome!";
  document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = name;
}

function myFunction() {
  // Gets input value
  var name = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  // Saves data to retrieve later
  localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
  
  // Updates HTML
  updateHTML();
}
```

Note that your code was ok; the only problem was that 2 lines were outside the function, that's all.
Then, in your other page, you can use the updateHTML function:

```js
updateHTML();
```

EDIT: I've made an additional function so you can reuse the code when you just have only to retrieve the data. Also, it is always a good idea to separate the code so it is easier to understand and maintain. Hope it helped; let me know if not.

Comment: It did help a lot! Thank you so much!!
Now I'm only having trouble using the stored name on the second page, but in the middle of a sentence... Like, having a header that says "Welcome back (userName)."

Comment: I've made another change to the code, take a look at it; I've separated 1 line and made it another function. Now you can do: "Welcome back "+getName()+"." on the second page.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your kind help! I am still a beginner, and I have learnt a lot with your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem Findings:

```
localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userName")
```

above two lines executed before preparing your DOM of HTML,
so
***localStorage.setItem("userName", name);***//name is empty

***document.getElementById("storedName")*** //innerHTML is null

thats why raised exception ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null***

Your java script function should be change like below

```
    function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello, " + name + "! Welcome!";
localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userName");
}
```

and whenever you need to display local storage data in any pages then you should check the storage availability first then use

example:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("userName")!=undefined || localStorage.getItem("userName")!==null){
//To Do
}
```