# How do I prevent the content from disappearing after refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Happy New Year! So, I was making a calculator with HTML, CSS and JS. I wanted that the content in the `input` to not disappear even after refreshing the page. I couldn't figure it out and wanted some help. I have not added a lot of logic into the calculator so please ignore that.

Below is the code:

---

```js
var text = document.getElementById("field");

function type(word) {
  text.value += word;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: right;
}

td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
}

td:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <input type="text" id="field" maxlength="11">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="type('%')">%</td>
        <td onclick="text.value=''">C</td>
        <td onclick="type(')')">)</td>
        <td onclick="type('÷')">÷</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="type('7')">7</td>
        <td onclick="type('8')">8</td>
        <td onclick="type('9')">9</td>
        <td onclick="type('×')">×</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="type('4')">4</td>
        <td onclick="type('5')">5</td>
        <td onclick="type('6')">6</td>
        <td onclick="type('-')">-</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="type('1')">1</td>
        <td onclick="type('2')">2</td>
        <td onclick="type('3')">3</td>
        <td onclick="type('+')">+</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td onclick="type('(-')">+/-</td>
        <td onclick="type('0')">0</td>
        <td onclick="type('.')">.</td>
        <td>=</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you talking about hitting Ctrl-R on the browser and `field` gets reset to an empty value? that's normal and is similar to turning off a calculator and turning it back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input will always be cleared when you refresh the page. A simple way to retain the input value would be to use the `localStorage` API.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505323/save-input-value-to-local-storage-and-retrieve-it-on-a-different-page) may be helpful.